# Accessing a WCF webservice hosted on AWS virtual machine

Tags: c#, wcf, amazon-web-services

I currently have a Web service deployed on a virtual machine hosted by Amazon Web Services (the free one) that access data in a SQL database on that same machine.  Using my local test harness I am able to confirm the service is working as expected.  It is able to connect to the database and interact as expected.

However, I am having difficulty accessing that web service from the internet.    I was hoping somebody can confirm if that is even possible, and if so point me towards a solution that will allow external access.  The Web Service is writen in C# using WCF and REST

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How are you trying to connect to your WCF service over the internet? Have you written a client (and if so, can you tell us more about it) or are you using a tool (or even a browser)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You have to attach an elastic public IP to the instance. Does the management console show a public IP?
You'll also have to create a security group that allows http access from the internet (0.0.0.0/0).